# Find the inclination of the legs to the horizontal, and the height of the apex.

Tags: trigonometry

The legs of a tripod are each $10$ cm. in length,and their points of contact with a horizontal table on which the tripod stands from a triangle whose sides are $7,8,9$ cm in length.Find the inclination of the legs to the horizontal, and the height of the apex.

---

I do not have idea how to find the inclination of  the legs.I can not give any worth mentioning input from my side.

Comment: All angles of inclination must be equal because they rise to equal height. Now you can use coordinate geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be the triangle with $AB=7,BC=8,CA=9$, and let $D$ be the apex.

Also, let $R$ be the circumradius of the triangle, and let $O$ be the circumcenter.

Let $O'$ be the point on the plane on which the triangle exists such that $DO'$ is perpendicular to the plane. Then, having that $\triangle{DO'A}\cong\triangle{DO'B}\cong\triangle{DO'C}$ implies $O'A=O'B=O'C$, i.e. $O'=O$.

By the law of cosines,
$$7^2=8^2+9^2-2\cdot 8\cdot 9\cdot\cos\angle{ACB}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \cos\angle{ACB}=\frac{2}{3}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \sin{\angle{ACB}}=\frac{\sqrt 5}{3}$$
since $\angle{ACB}$ is acute.

Hence, by the law of sines,
$$\frac{AB}{\sin{\angle{ACB}}}=2R\quad\Rightarrow\quad R=\frac{21}{2\sqrt 5}$$
Thus, 
$$\cos\angle{DAO}=\frac{AO}{DA}=\frac{R}{10}=\frac{21}{20\sqrt 5}$$

$$\Rightarrow\quad \text{(the inclination of the legs to the horizontal)}=\angle{DAO}=\arccos\left(\frac{21\sqrt 5}{100}\right)\approx 62^\circ$$
and
$$\text{(the height of the apex)}=DO=\sqrt{DA^2-AO^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1559}{20}}\approx 8.8\ \text{(cm)}$$

Comment: Can't we simply find the circumradius(r) and take arccos $(\frac {r}{10})$ ?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: sorry, but I don't get what you mean. I found $R$ and took $\arccos(R/10)$, didn't I?

Comment: Wait so their isn't a closed form equation for finding radius?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: sorry, but I don't get it. I wrote $R=21/(2\sqrt 5)$ in my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry! It's hard to scroll down on my mobile.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: No problem.